# Achieving "stable" references to objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Imagine the following array of objects representing individual people.

```
let people = [

    {
        name: 'Alice',
        age: 19
    },
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: 32
    },
]
```

You are asked to loop over each object and to add the person's hair and eye color to their object. Fortunately, your task is simplified by the fact that they both have brown hair and hazel eyes. For some reason, you decide to use a **property accessor** for Alice and a **destructuring  assignment** for Bob. Finally, you log the result.

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    let person = people[i];

    if (person.name === 'Alice') {
        person.hair = 'brown';
        person.eyes = 'hazel';
    }

    else if (person.name === 'Bob') {
        let additionalInfo = {
            hair: 'brown',
            eye: 'hazel'
        }
        person = { ...person, ...additionalInfo }
    }
}

people.forEach(person => console.log(person));
```

However, the new information is present in Alice's object but not in Bob's!

```
{ name: 'Alice', age: 19, hair: 'brown', eyes: 'hazel' }
{ name: 'Bob', age: 32 }
```

Now, I understand why Alice's object gets updated: `person.hair = 'brown'` get treated as `people[i].hair = 'brown'` because `person === people[i]`.

I *somewhat but not fully* understand why this doesn't work with Bob in this example. On one hand, we are reassigning the person variable to something other than `people[i]`, thereby losing the reference, and `person` is lost after that iteration with no changes made to Bob's object.

On the other hand, my initial expectation was that changes to `person` would result in changes to `people[i]` because `person === people[i]`. Hence it is a little surprising the fix here is to swap out `person = { ...person, ...additionalInfo }` with `people[i] = { ...person, ...additionalInfo }`.

Why is this the case? Is it even possible to create a "stable reference" to an object in JS such that changes to the variable containing the reference are applied to the object it is referring to?

Comment: `person = ...` means your are assigning a new value to the local variable `person`. That will not affect `people[i]`.

Comment: *"...and a destructuring assignment for Bob..."* That isn't destructuring assignment. Quite the opposite, it's **structuring** assignment (creating an object) using spread syntax.

Comment: And the answer to your question about "stable" references is no. You cannot alias an object property or variable with another variable. You can in a language like C++ because you can make a variable an explicit reference type, but you can't in JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is not the destructuring assignment, the problem is that you forgot that the syntax `{}` is shorthand for `new Object()`. You are creating a new object, and assigning it to the variable `person`. So now `person` is pointing to that new object instead of `people[i]`

Comment: @Pointy Actually, even in C++ he'll have problems with code like this when he forgets that doing something like `a = new X()` does not change the content of what `a` previously pointed to but instead assigns the address to a new object to it.

Comment: @slebetman yes, true, and it's been a long time since I endured C++ :)

Comment: The task itself is strange. The only way to use destructuring assignment to update an object is: `;({ hair : person.hair, eye: person.eye } = additionalInfo);` Which is very hacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, my initial expectation was that changes to `person` would result in changes to `people[i]` because `person === people[i]`.

That's true for changes to what `person`/`people[i]` *point to* (the object), but not true for `person` *the variable*. The value in a variable (or property) that makes that variable refer to an object is called an *object reference*. When you assign to `person`, you're changing what's in the `person` variable (in your case, so that it points to a different object entirely).

You start out with something like this in memory (the "Ref12345" values are just for clarity, the numbers don't mean anything):

```
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           +−−>|   (object)    |   
                           |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   | name: "Alice" |   
people−−−>| (array)     |  |   | age: 19       |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | 0: Ref13521 |−−+
          | 1: Ref24612 |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
                                       v
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
person: Ref24612−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   (object)    |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
                               | name: "Bob"   |
                               | age: 32       |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

but then when you do `person = ___`, you change the *value* of `person` (which object `person` points to), making it point to a whole different object that `people[i]` doesn't point to:

```
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           +−−>|   (object)    |   
                           |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   | name: "Alice" |   
people−−−>| (array)     |  |   | age: 19       |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | 0: Ref13521 |−−+
          | 1: Ref24612 |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
                                       v
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
                               |   (object)    |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
                               | name: "Bob"   |
                               | age: 32       |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
person: Ref74324−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   (object)    |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               | name: "Bob"   |
                               | age: 32       |
                               | hair: "brown" |
                               | eyes: "hazel" |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

> Is it even possible to create a "stable reference" to an object in JS...

Object references in JavaScript *are* stable. This is just how *variables* work. (Not only in JavaScript, but also in many other languages with object references, such as Java, C#, PHP, ...) You could use a `const` for `person` instead of `let`: `let person = people[i];` That would prevent you changing the value in `person`, so you *couldn't* point it at a different object. That would let you do the changes you did for Alice (modifying the object) but not Bob (creating a new object and having `person` point to it).

Answer (score 2):

no,

`person` and `people[i]` are two reference to same thing..

when you assign to a reference it updates what it is pointing to

eg.

`let a = {x:1}`

if you do

`b = a`

`b` is not the object `{x:1}` .. it merely points to that object

when you do `b.x = 3` . that works because you say  `change the x property on the object b is pointing to`

but when you do

`b = {y:2}`

now you are saying `b` should point to this new object.. `a` still points to the older object and nothing changes there.